# Discover all DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two DbContext in my application, which configure some models with Fluent API. One model of my first DbContext has a foreign key to a second model configured in my second DbContext.

```
    public class UserData
    {
        public double Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string FullName {
            get {
                return $"{this.FirstName} {this.LastName}";
            }
        }

        public string Adress1 { get; set; }

        public virtual BaseUserTreeData BaseUserTree { get; set; }
        public double? BaseUserTreeId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<DeviceData> Devices { get; set; }
    }
```

The model `BaseUserTreeData` is my foreign property configured in my second DbContext.

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BaseUserTreeData>().ToTable("sw_data_baseusertree");

            modelBuilder.Entity<BaseUserTreeData>().Property(baseusertree => baseusertree.Id).HasColumnName("baseusertree_ID");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BaseUserTreeData>().Property(baseusertree => baseusertree.Label).HasColumnName("label");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BaseUserTreeData>().Property(baseusertree => baseusertree.ParentTreeId).HasColumnName("baseUserTree_ID_parent");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BaseUserTreeData>().HasKey(baseusertree => baseusertree.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BaseUserTreeData>()
                .HasOptional(tree => tree.ParentTree)
                .WithMany(tree => tree.ChildTrees)
                .HasForeignKey(tree => tree.ParentTreeId);
        }
```

When I use `UserData` with my `UserDbContext` for the first time, the `OnModelCreating` of my second `DbContext` is not called, so `BaseUserTreeData` mapping is not executed, and the query generated by Entity Framework 6 is wrong. I saw that I can share `EntityConfiguration` in separate classes, but is there a way to tell to EF6 to call every `OnModelCreating` of all my `DbContext`?

Comment: why do you need 2 `contexts` here ?

Comment: Because I want to use my second DbContext without all the entities of the first DbContext

Comment: then for what you use that ? which problem are you going to solve using that pattern ?

Comment: I want to have a weak link between my contexts. But maybe all models which have a relation have to be mapped and used in the same context ?  I don't want to use big contexts, that's why I want to separate contexts

Comment: is this `web app` or `desktop app` ?

Comment: This is a Web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're in wrong path.This is not a recommended way of handling `Context`.If there is `too strong relationship` between models, you have to concentrate the models inside `one unique context`.Otherwise you'll have to face so many issues in the future.So my advice is to use the pattern which `EF team` suggested below.

This is the way **Microsoft EF Team** has suggested :

> When working with Web applications, use a context instance per
>   request.

You can read more about `context` handling using below articles :

[**Working with DbContext**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx)

[**Managing DbContext the right way with Entity Framework**](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)

Comment: We already follow this recommandation, one context instance per request, but sometimes we use 2 kind of context in one request. But you're right, if there is too strong relationship between models, we have to concentrate the models inside one unique context.

Comment: yes,it is true.I have updated my post to reflect your comment too.